# Sticky scrollview subview has incorrect frame after scrolling fast. Compilable example

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have spent the past 12 hours futzing with this and I'm going braindead.

> view on bitbucket:
>   `https://bitbucket.org/burneraccount/scrollviewexample`
>
> git https: `https://bitbucket.org/burneraccount/scrollviewexample.git`
>
> git ssh: `git@bitbucket.org:burneraccount/scrollviewexample.git`

^ That is a condensed, self-contained Xcode project that exemplifies the problem I'm having in my real work.

**Summary**

I am trying to achieve a static-image effect, where the image (a rock in the example) appears stuck to the screen while the lower content scrolls upwards appearing to go above the scrollview.

There's a screen-sized `(UIScrollView*)mainScrollView`. This scrollview has a `(UIView*)contentView`. `contentView` is ~1200 pts long and has two subviews: (UIScrollView*)imageScroller and (UITextView*)textView.

[image: one]

All works well until you scroll up a little bit, then scroll down really fast. The resulting position after movement stops is incorrect. It somehow doesn't update properly in the `scrollviewDidScroll` delegate method. The fast downward scroll (only after you've dragged up) behaves somewhat correctly, but still results in a misplaced view:

[image: two]

gently dragging does almost nothing, and the velocity of the scroll is directly related to the incorrect offset.

Here is the offending code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.mainScrollView)
    {

        CGFloat mainOffset = self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y;
        if (mainOffset > 0 && mainOffset < self.initialImageScrollerFrame.size.height)
        {
            CGRect imageFrame = self.imageScroller.frame;
            CGFloat offset = mainOffset-self.lastOffset;
            self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(imageFrame.origin.x,
                                                  imageFrame.origin.y + offset, // scroll up
                                                  imageFrame.size.width,
                                                  imageFrame.size.height - offset); // hide the bottom of the image
            self.lastOffset = mainOffset;
        }

    }
}
```

I've restructured this in almost every way I could imagine and it always has similar effects. The worst part is how the very simple and straightforward code fails to do what is seems like it's guaranteed to do. 
Also odd is that the zoom-effect I use in my real project works fine using the same mechanism to size the same view element. It runs inside `(contentOffset < 0)` instead of `(contentOffset > 0)`, so it only zoom in on the `imageScroller` when you're pulling the view below it's normal offset. That leads me to conspire that some data is lost as it crosses the `contentOffset 0`, but my conspiracies have been shot down all day.

This is example is a lot less complicated than the real project I'm working on, but it properly reproduces the problem. Please let me know if you can't open my project, or can't connect to the repo.

There is likely a largely obvious fix for this, but I am hours past the point of having any new perspective. I will be thoroughly amazed if I ever get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.mainScrollView)
    {

        CGFloat mainOffset = self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y;
        if (mainOffset >= 0 && mainOffset < self.initialImageScrollerFrame.size.height)
        {
            CGRect imageFrame = self.imageScroller.frame;
            CGFloat offset = self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y-self.lastOffset;
            if ( imageFrame.origin.y + offset > 0) {  //[2]
                self.imageScroller.frame = CGRectMake(imageFrame.origin.x,
                                                      imageFrame.origin.y + offset, 
                                                      imageFrame.size.width,
                                                      imageFrame.size.height - offset); 
                self.lastOffset = mainOffset;
            }
        }else if (mainOffset < 0) {  //[1]
            self.imageScroller.frame = self.initialImageScrollerFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

[1] - When your `mainOffset` goes below zero, you need to reset your imageScroller frame. ScrollViewDidScroll does not register with every pixel's-worth of  movement, it is only called every so often (try logging it, you will see). So as you scroll faster, it's offsets are further apart. This can result in a positive scroll of say +15 becoming a negative scroll on the next call to scrollViewDiDScroll. So your imageScroller.frame.y may get stuck on that +15 offset even when you expect it to be zero.Thus as soon as you detect a negative value for mainOffset, you need to reset your imageScroller frame.

[2] - similarly here you need to ensure here that your imageScroller.frame.y will always be +ve.

These fixes do the job, but I would still consider them "ugly and not production-worthy". For a cleaner approach you might want to reconsider the interplay between these views, and what you are trying to achieve.

By the way, your 'image.png' is actually a jpg. While these renders fine on the simulator, it will break (with compiler errors) on a device.

Comment: Great answer, much appreciated. Would you give me a high level idea of what you think would be the cleanest approach? I also tried setting the imageScroller behind the mainScrollview, but I still had the same issue.

Comment: @user, it's difficult to describe a clean approach without knowing more what you are trying to achieve in your real project - which is beyond the scope of this question. But i wonder why you are embedding the horizontal-scrolling imageScroller inside another vertical-scrolling mainView at all, given that the imageScroller should remain stationary with respect to that mainView. I would have thought you could treat it as a sibling inside the same superView to achieve the same result without all of this offset calculation and repositioning.

Comment: The desired effect is to have the text content scroll over top of the image scroller. This is a production application with a few engineers working on it, and I wanted to implement this effect with as little change to the current implementation as possible (so the other developers wouldn't have to re-think this controller when making new changes).

Comment: Would you yourself put the `imageScroller` behind the (screen-sized)`mainScrollview` and have a transparent window of the same height pass down touch events, or would you put the `imageScroller` directly above the `mainScrollview` and increase the `origin->y` of the main scrollView as the user scrolls up (because the default behavior then keeps the scrolling text content inside of the mainScrollview's bounds and below `mainScrollview.origin.y`)?

Comment: @user, I have an interesting alternative approach which I can suggest for you - but I think you should open a new question, as the answer will stray too much from your original. Whatever, I will give you a decent outline tomorrow (it's late ;-j)

Comment: I've made a dedicated question. Very curious to hear your approach :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860545/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-scrollview-with-a-sticky-horizontal-scro

Comment: Hey, pull from the repo again and `checkout StackOverflow` I implemented your suggestion and it works, but doesn't kick in until ~80 pixels of offset

Comment: @user, you just missed the `else if...` clause. I guess you didn't like my [other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20861114/1375695)!

Comment: Ahh okay. I'm just trying to get a quick mockup to run past the rest of the team, I'll definitely be using your suggested implementation if anything goes to production. I actually found a good [screencast](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/75-a-tale-of-uiscrollview-customization) that uses your suggestion for a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my updates here.

One answerer mentioned `- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and while that doesn't apply here, the similar `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` does. In my struggles yesterday I implemented

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y < 10)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.imageScroller.frame = self.initialImageScrollerFrame;

        }];
    }
}
```

and this is somewhat of a workaround, but it's ugly and definitely not production-worthy. It just animated the frame back to its original position if the contentOffset is close enough to 0. It's a step in the right direction, but I'm afraid it doesn't deserve merit as a solution.

**----**

Also added

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    CGPoint point = *targetContentOffset;
    CGFloat offset = point.y;

    if (0 <= offset && offset < 10)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.imageScroller.frame = self.initialImageScrollerFrame;
        }];
    }
}
```

which brings me closer to the intended effect, but still remains unusable for a production application.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue but for add another functionality, button for left/right listing UIScrollView, after fast tapping on it, scroll view is broke my brain ;(

I think better scrolling without animation, it preventing glitches for UIScrollView content. May be it is not answer, but...

Answer (score -1):

Hey mate use the below method that might help you out, its a delegate method of UIScrollView:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

And within this method you can change the scrollview frame as x and y to  0,0

Comment: I've played with this delegate method already (although that doesn't mean there's not a potential solution here). But I don't want the scrollview to be set to zero every time the scrolling stops.

Comment: The scroll view calls this method at the end of its implementations of the setContentOffset:animated: and scrollRectToVisible:animated: methods, but only if animations are requested. I'm not using those methods, but I did try `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` and that didn't prove helpful. Feel free to clone my example and try your solution.